# Как из url удалить часть параметров

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Получаю параметры с помощью urllib:

```
from urllib import parse

for url in urls:
    all_instances = parse.urlparse(url).query
    dict_from_query = parse.parse_qs(query)
```

Есть список ненужных параметров:

```
qw = ["perpage", "h"]
```

И список ссылок:

```
urls = ["google.com/news?page=1&perpage=20", "google.com/news?h=34748fdg&page=20", "google.com/news?h=jshjdfh5&perpage=20"]
```

Как из ссылок удалить ненужные параметры, чтобы получить в итоге следующий список:

```
urls = ["google.com/news?page=1", "google.com/news?page=20", "google.com/news"]
```

Comment: `del dict_from_query['perpage']`

Comment: @splash58, если проходить циклом по ключам и сравнивать например с каким-то множеством ненужных параметров, то такой метод не подойдет, будет ошибка изменение размера словаря во время итерации

Comment: значит, пишите нужные в другой словарь newQuery и подмените в all_instances

Comment: а почему во второй сохранился perpage?

Comment: исправила, спасибо

Comment: и какие у вас проблемы возникли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае лучше воспользоваться готовыми решениями

```
for i in range(len(urls)):
    url = parse.urlparse(urls[i])
    # получаем query в виде списка кортежей
    query = parse.parse_qsl(url.query)
    newQuery = dict()
    for k, v in query:
        # берем только нужные
        if k not in qw:
            newQuery[k] = v
    # строим новый урл
    # Результат urlparse не позволяет обновлять атрибуты,
    # но можно создать копию с измененными данными
    newUrl = url._replace(query=parse.urlencode(newQuery))
    urls[i] = parse.urlunparse(newUrl)

print(urls)  #  ['google.com/news?page=1', 'google.com/news?page=20', 'google.com/news']
```

Answer (score 1):

раз вопрос про регулярки, то вот мой вариант, неказистый, но вроде работает:

```
from re import sub

qw = ["perpage", "h"]
urls = ["google.com/news?page=1&perpage=20", 
        "google.com/news?h=34748fdg&page=20", 
        "google.com/news?h=jshjdfh5&perpage=20"]

for i in range(len(urls)):
    urls[i] = sub(fr'&?(?:{"|".join(qw)})=.*?(?=&|$)&?', '', urls[i]).rstrip('?')

print(urls)  # ['google.com/news?page=1', 'google.com/news?page=20', 'google.com/news']
```

Comment: спасибо за решение. а можете пожалуйста объяснить это выражение fr'&?(?:{"|".join(qw)})=.*?(?=&|$)&?'

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, могу только в общих чертах: это выражение находит подстроку состоящую из любого элемента списка qw ("|"  = "ИЛИ") после которого стоит знак =, после которого следует несколько символов (.*?), которые стоят перед символом & либо в конце строки (?=&|$) и вся эта подстрока может (символ - ?) начинаться или заканчиваться символом &.

Comment: спасибо большое, теперь все понятно)